# Mysqldump of the AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I want to take a back up of the RDS MYsql database. I am running a small instance presently. I need procedure to get a sqldump, but my question is does RDS freezes while taking a sqldump, since in its production lot of read/write operations happen. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

To answer the exact question, "Does RDS freeze while taking a sqldump":

If you are looking to backup for RDS usage, i would recommend you to use RDS Snapshots.In this case a brief I/O freeze, typically lasting a few seconds, occurs on Single-AZ DB instances.The Database needs to be freezed to avoid corruption.If you are using an external dump utility like mysqldump, it locks your tables with a read lock before dumping them.Depending on your storage engine, the UPDATES (and possibly SELECTS) will be queued up until the dump is complete after which it unlocks the tables.

If you are unsure , you could read lock them yourself

`flush tables with read lock;`

and then unlock them , once the dump is finished.

`unlock tables;`