# Amazon-RDS database to Dedicated server

Tags: amazon-web-services, dump, amazon-rds, data-transfer, dedicated-server

I went through this answer here: [Mysqldump of the AWS RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705129/mysqldump-of-the-aws-rds)
But, apparently, it gave me no clue.

**What I intend to do?**

I have an RDS instance running on amazon and database is about 450+ tables, which is an insane amount of data for mysqldump. I wish to have it dumped so that I can migrate it from AwS to Dedicated.

**What is the problem?**

It freezes once I start taking the dump via adminer. Snapshot gives a format which can be used from one region to another but, I wish to have it in say.. SQL format (to keep it simple) and then transfer it to my dedicated server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 450+ tables, which is an insane amount of data for sqldump

Assuming you mean [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html), that's not an accurate statement.  I routinely use mysqldump on systems with 10,000+ tables and hundreds of millions of rows.  Restoring the data on the new server may take some time, but that's true of anything stored in what you called "SQL format."

The `--single-transaction` option in mysqldump will extract a consistent snapshot of all InnoDB tables; the `--compress` option to mysqldump will use the mysql compressed client/server protocol to reduce the time it takes to extract the data without changing the contents of the dump file; and of course the `--events` `--triggers` and `--routines` options are important.

Comment: yes, I meant mysqldump. How long does it take for you to dump 10000+ tables and hundreds of millions of rows? For me 40GiB seems a lot and besides, my adminer on the server wont even load the contents properly. What would be effect way to 'back up' from the dbase.

Comment: Consider replying to my comment there?

Comment: 10k tables, 300M rows, 4 hours to make a backup. Don't use my adminer, if it doesn't work. :) Just use the `mysql` command line client utility.