# RDS MySQL Data to a Flat File to Reload in another MySQL - Std CLI Not Working

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, data-migration

*To establish precident I reviewed the following:*

- [Amazon-RDS database to Dedicated server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153462/amazon-rds-database-to-dedicated-server)
- [Mysqldump of the AWS RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705129/mysqldump-of-the-aws-rds)
- I have not however found a clear cut solution to my issues in these,
  and only ancillary factoids throughout - I wanted to put a
  comprehensive specific guide to moving data into/around AWS RDS.

  I did have a discussion at the Percona MySQL performance conference
  with a DBA consultant who works with RDS, he suggested the following,
  and this is apparently an issue frequently - I wanted additional
  input in the effort to help everyone.

** This is important for RDS users according to a Large MySQL Consulting firm and the number of hands raised at the talk.**

- Goal #1. Get the data out of your RDS Instance
  -You can't move between major releases within RDS.
  -Maybe you want to take it to EC2 instance like Percona, etc.
- Wish List Goal # 1a. Secondarily, Clean/QA the data up if possible,
- Goal #3 - Get the Data back into another smaller RDS, or other
  flavor/platform.

The facts:

1. I have a large (40-50GB dataset in utf-8 primarily, some latin-1) in MySQL 5.5.x (<5.5.8).
   1a. The old admin for whatever reason set our instance size to 1000GB of dedicated storage that is just padding. (?).
2. All tables are now, obviously InnoDB - a couple tables are approx ~14GB. That's another issue.
3. Multi encode may exist: perhaps UTF8; Latin-1 and Swedish-fkafkakfk?

**So with that these are options I am debating to proceed with:**

**Option A: Straight .sql dump; .sql reload**

1. Dump, in .sql standard executables the schema and tables etc en masse, reload.
2. **So was thininking latin-1 for portability:
   `mysqldump -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 -N database > backup.sql`
   `mysql -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 database < backup.sql**`

> ***Question RE: Option A:*** 
>   - Suggestions re: above code, for chunking, integrity and otherwise guaranteeing a smooth dump and reload? Contingencies for `show
>   information schema` with variable encodes (Algorithm for handling what latin1 can't?)

**Option B: Individual ascii file dumps of tables w/Schema + QA/Schema refinement**

1. Dump, in straight ASCII (Charset? UTF-8? I must be careful?) these data into, separate respective tables, perhaps in chunks for data QA.

   Would proceed with the following to output TSV DATA and SCHEMA:

   `mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --tab=~/output/dir dbname`
2. Secondarily, run through some perl/python to clean up possible errant junk chars; encoding issues; etc from 8 years of 5 different DBAs and about 12 different data input format/file types.

Questions RE: Option B:

> - My data has a lot of garbage chars that are true to the data; Pipe delim the best?
> - I've had horrendous errors loading into AWS RDS from TSV etc from basic dumps, suggestions beyond what is published in their data loading whitepaper?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest Option C, which is to use an ETL tool to move the data. I have used the Community edition of Pentaho Data Integration very successfully to do the sort of things you're asking about (especially the cleanup). It's more work than a simple dump and load, but you have very good control and can do things like sync up again later and so on.